# Where to specify localhost port in VS Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code

I am building an `ASP.NET` Core app and am wanting to use a specific port when launching debug in `VS Code`. It defaults to running `http:// localhost:5000`. I am unable to find any setting for where I would change this. When I try to specify a `port` setting in the `launch.json` file, I am being alerted that it is not allowed. Is there a specific setting to set for specifying which `port`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Program.cs`

try to add    `.UseUrls("http://localhost:5050")`

Port number can be anything other than the specified one

Comment: This code should be removed when moving to a production instance. For just local debugging using VS Code, there are environment variables that can be set using the launch.json file

Comment: @MitchGollub I want to inform these two things 1. This was asked an Year back and it was a pure `asp.net core` answer 2. OP didn't mentioned that he need for production instance and my answer didn't contradict in another way.

Answer (score 32):

You can configure this from the launch.json file.  You want to find the "env" property and add

```
"ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>"
```

Adjusting from the default launch.json it should look something like this:

```
"env": {
     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
     "ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://localhost:5001"
},
```

This way your port change will only affect your locally running application and you won't be adding debugging code to your production application

Comment: This works--if I manually browse to 
   http://localhost:5000/index.html

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to remove this when you deploy to staging or production?
This doesnt seem good for anything but local dev.

Answer (score 0):

You can define any port number in the launch.json file like below (Reference code taken for Django application run)

```
       "args": [
            "runserver", "3300",
        ],
```