# Cannot open localhost (ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a very basic asp.net core (WebAPI) project with V.S. Code to show some values on webpage. But it gave the error:

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://localhost:5000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

I used all browsers to open this website but got the same result of failing to load the website. I tried nearly every suggestions through internet search. such as turn firewall/anti-virus off, delete or add listeners with netsh, change network proxy setting etc. But nothing works for me. Could you give me a suggestion what's the possible root cause of this issue. Thanks.

There are two pictures to show the err information.

[This site can’t be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDB16.jpg)

[Network Headers with Dev Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwIEC.jpg)

Comment: You might try verifying the port number or changing to another and trying again --   [instrucs here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358769/where-to-specify-localhost-port-in-vs-code)

Comment: Is port 5000 configured as HTTPS instead of HTTP? If so, try `https://localhost:5000/`

Comment: Try this. Start your web api project with debugging enabled. I.e. Hit F5 on your visual studio.

Comment: Are you using a proxy or VPN? If yes, make sure it is turned off.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.In fact this problem stuck me for several weeks. I tried to change the port number and used HTTPS, also the proxy server has been deselected. But nothing help. For some unknown reason, the website began to work for several days and then it returned to not working again.

Comment: The only thing is that my windows is 32bit so I cannot debug the project with v.s. code. For some unknown reason, the website began to work for several days and then a couple of days ago, it became nonworking again. Before that I just deleted and installed several extensions. Right now I tried to keep just C# extension, but it is still not working.

Comment: Check the application logs to see on what port the app is actually being hosted. If there’s no response on port 5000, then that likely means that it is not running on port 5000.

Comment: Thank you. I just reset the system a couple of days ago and it works well now.